# Use Spring boot only for development

Tags: maven, configuration, spring-boot

I am kind of newbie to maven configuration and using spring-boot .
I want to use spring boot but I only want it to be active for development, when I deploy the artifact to other environments like QA or Production I want to generate a war, and I dont want to have any spring-boot dependecy.

How could I accomplish this ? 
This is my current pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxxx</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>xxxxxxx</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.0</jackson.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<!--    
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
 -->

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

</build>
</project>
```

I have heard a bit about maven profiles , but I am not sure how it works, and if it is the best solutions for this use case. Basically what I want, It is to introduce spring-boot dependencies only for development stage and keep the current ones for production and qa stages.

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. You do know that you can package a war with Spring Boot, right? If I had to paraphrase, it's like if you'd like to use Hibernate for development and then in production remove it and expect things to work. What's the problem having spring boot in production?

Comment: Your `pom.xml` is not showing any dependency on Spring Boot at the moment. You disabled the parent and you are not using any starter. Maybe I'm wrong but do you just want to use boot in development so you can skip the part of installing a web container and deploying the app there? If yes you can still achieve this. The packaging as a `war` file of a boot app is perfectly doable. But the you should also try to use a starter or go the complete non Boot way.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't have a dynamic parent. However, just setting spring boot as parent will not bring you any dependencies, it will only provide you access to the properties and `dependencyManagement` and will help you manage dependency versions easier.